why does native speaker spoken 回去 sound like it has an extra "e" at the end?
I was listening to this video https://www.facebook.com/share/r/Ai4GhbQHFsifuDiX/
And listening to native speakers say 回去 and it sounds like "hui que" as opposed to "hui qu"
Is it just me and I am hearing it wrong?

It is a local dialect, but I am not sure where.

回去用普通话读是hui qu。
我发现视频里第一个读回去的人好像确实读成了hui que，出现这种情况是因为她本人发音不标准。
发音最标准的是中国官方媒体宣传的主持人，比如CCTV，中文国际等等，这些主持人发音很标准。

I want to dive in a little bit to your question since the accent should be from my hometown.
The woman who speaks 回去 is the actress
汤唯 in the movie 色·戒. Her accent of 去 belongs to 四川 / Sichuan dialect in my hearing, where multiple other accents of 去 are also available. See “去”在四川话里为什么分读为 qi 、ki 、ji 、qie ？ for details.
For a systematical thinking, you can search the term literary and colloquial dialect, e.g. in Sichuanese dialects from wikipedia.

原问题中说把去读作(que)的应该是汤唯前面说去的那个女人。

去 - /tɕʰy˥˩/ (std Mandrin); /tɕʰie˨˩˧/ and /tɕʰy˨˩˧/ (Sichuan dialects). See the linked article.

The word 去 is used very frequently and can be heard in many different situations. Though it is officially pronounced in pinyin as qu, people often say it like qi, que, or qie. For example,
离我远点儿，滚一边去。(qi) speaking lightly.
去你妈的。(qu) speaking clearly.

"离我远点儿，滚一边去。(qi) speaking lightly". should be "离我远点儿，滚一边去。(qu)." In here, 去 read as qu, 对于去，在普通话中基本上没有其他读法，中国大陆人只读作qu，。
